# Two different constructors that have two different classes

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have two different constructors in a file because I have two different classes.

Example :

in animal.h file

```
class Animal
{
  .... 
}

class Pet: public Animal 
{
  ... 
}
```

in my animal.cpp :

```
 Animal::Animal()
 {
 }

 Pet::Pet()
 {
 }
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you running into some issue? Get more details -- error messages or undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Technically: Yes, it is possible. The usual file structure with `*.cpp` and `*.h` or `*.hpp` files is just a **convention**. The language does not keep you from defining constructors or other member functions for two different classes in the same source file.

**animal.h:**

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
};

#endif
```

**pet.h:**

```
#ifndef PET_H
#define PET_H

#include "animal.h"

class Pet : public Animal
{
public:
    Pet();
};

#endif
```

**animal.cpp:**

```
#include "pet.h"

Pet::Pet() {}

Animal::Animal() {}
```

Whether you *should* do this is a different story altogether. Usually, this will make your project structure harder to understand and harder to maintain. The example given above is a particularly bad case which any competent C++ programmer would want to refactor.